# Installation of Fuerte under Fedora 14

Tags: ros, python, ros-fuerte, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I followed the instructions and everything went fine until the cmake stuff.
[Fedora Installation Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Fedora)

> cmake ..
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
> -- +++ catkin
> -- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM)  CMake Error at
> catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:29 (message):
> Unable to find either executable
> 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
> installing package 'python-empy' Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
> catkin/cmake/all.cmake:51 (include)
> catkin/CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)

any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38905/installation-of-fuerte-under-fedora-14/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are missing the [EmPy Python package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/EmPy/3.1/). On Ubuntu that is installed as a Debian package dependency.

Maybe there is a corresponding Fedora 14 package. If so, I would use it.

Otherwise, try installing it with pip:

```
sudo pip install -U EmPy
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3